# What are the differences between parseInt(x) and +(x) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, parseint

By using parseInt(x), we can get an integer value from a string. But same functionality we can achieve from +(x) also. What exactly the functional difference are.
Ex:

```
let input = '123';
let output = parseInt(input); // gives output as integer 123
let output = +(input); // gives output as integer 123
```

Comment: You can also use `~~('3')`.

Answer (score 1):

- The **parseInt()** function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems)whereas the **unary +** acts more like **parseFloat** since it also accepts decimals.
- The parseFloat() function parses a string and returns a floating point number.
- Therefore if you are validating user input, unary plus has correct behavior for everything except it accepts decimals, whereas parseInt is too liberal.
- Here the String that you entered(ie, '123') does not have decimal point. So the output will be same.

Comment: `parseFloat(false)`.